# Удалить тег img в случае если картинка не загрузилась (не доступна) без jQuery

Tags: javascript

Нужно везде удалить тег img, в случае если картинка не загрузилась (не доступна).

Вот примерный код:

```
var img_error = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < img_error.length;i++) {
if (img_error[i].addEventListener) {
    img_error[i].addEventListener('error', handle_error, false);
}
else {
    img_error[i].attachEvent('onerror', handle_error);
}
delete img_error;
```

};

Как удалить все `img` с ошибкой?

Comment: Во первых надо определиться как будет идти проверка изображений, например после загрузки страницы запустить метод удаления или навесить таймер через каждые 5 секунд или один таймаут на все 30 секунд, во вторых изображения с ошибкой можно помечать своим уникальным атрибутом error_del , чтобы затем проходя по коллекции нод удалять отмеченные.

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < img_error.length;i++) {
  img_error[i].onload = function(){
   console.log("image loaded correctly"); 
  }
  
  img_error[i].onerror = function(){
   console.log("error loading image");
   this.remove();
  }
  ` ..... а если вы их динамически создаете.. то можно при создании тега `img` повесить эти обработчики

Comment: так? https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/8ywkbcb4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  var nodes = document.images,
    i = nodes.length - 1,
    img;
  for (; img = nodes[i--];)
    if (!img.complete || "naturalWidth" in new Image && !img.naturalWidth) img.parentNode.removeChild(img)
});
```

```css
 div img {
   border: 5px solid #8B4513;
 }
```

```html
<div>1
  <img src="https://" alt="">
</div>
<div>2
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
<div>3
  <img src="http://blog.jixee.me/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/BDie5.png" alt="" width="150">
</div>
<div>4
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
<div>5
  <img src="" alt="">
</div>
```

удаление незагрузившихся картинок после загрузки страницы на `js`

Comment: `naturalWidth` перебивает стили для изображения, заданные в css? и у меня почему-то не работает... это может быть потому, что у меня изображения подгружаются из json (т.е. путь к img прописан в json, который в свою очередь тоже подгружается со стороннего сервера) ? может какой-нибудь set timeout надо установить?

Comment: `(; img = nodes[i--];)` эта запись совсем не понятна

Comment: @Marina Voronova пока есть картинка с индексом i , прошу обратить внимание именно i а не i--, мы производим какие-то действия с переменной img, мой вариант для проверки после загрузки страницы, вам нужен тот что предложил @ Алексей Шиманский создали картинку прописали ей onerror и только потом присвоили src нужный url

Comment: у меня не работает